# Getting 404 on aws-sdk.min.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I woke up today to find my app not working. I'm getting a 404 on aws-sdk.min.js. It was working before...Is this a known issue?

Here is the script tag in my index.html:

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.7.27.min.js"></script>
```

I also did a npm install aws-sdk - following this guide: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk

[image]

[image]

Comment: That URL is accessible for me - have you tried it again?  Are you behind any sort of firewall or proxy?

Comment: I am testing it on my local so I doubt its a firewall issue.

Comment: The error says "from disk cache" - have you tried to either [force a refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache) or run in a private/incognito window?  Perhaps there was a brief failure and your browser cached that fact.